# GIT - New repository created from another -- merging?

Tags: git

I have created a new git repository based on another. They will slowly be diverging from each other.

But for now, is it ok to add a remote to the other repository I merged from in order to bring in commits?

It seems weird, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two repositories, let's call them `original` and `fork`. In order to create `fork`, you ran:

```
git clone path/to/original fork
```

Now you're doing work in `fork`, want to pull some of those changes into `original`, and are wondering if it's OK to add a remote in order to pull from `fork` into `original`:

```
cd path/to/original
git remote add fork path/to/fork
git remote update
git pull fork master
```

Yes, it's perfectly fine to do this. A remote just says that you want to be able to track what's going on in another repository, and possibly pull or push changes. Now, you cannot push changes to a non-bare repo (if both `original` and `fork` have working copies, then you can't push between them). But it's perfectly fine to add remotes for any repo you want, and pull changes in from branches in that repo, and even do the same on the other side afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There's effectively no difference between merging from the repo you cloned from and merging from a branch within your own repository. What matters is how the branches (or repositories) have diverged.

It's unclear from your question what the content in question is - you say "slowly diverging".

If the original begins to contain things that you don't want in your new repository, then merging is a bad idea.

If on the other hand, everything you do to the original *should* be propagated to the new one, then by all means, merge. (But I'm guessing you won't ever want to merge in the other direction.)

Finally, if these repositories represent two projects based on a common template, and you want to make changes to that template and share them between the two, the best thing to do would be to make a third repository which is *only* the template, and merge from that into each of the two, but never directly between the two.